# How to get child content of div on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this div structure after clicking inside class "4u" i am calling one click event but dont know how to get data inside `<p>` tag.

HTML:

```
<div class="4u 12u(mobile)">
    <section>
        <a href="#" class="image featured" id="dynamicCamping13"></a>
        <header id="dynamicCampingDesc13">
            <p>Loren ipsum</p>
        </header>
    </section>
</div>
```

Click event:

```
$(function() {
    $(".image").click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Read the documentation on DOM elements. It describes several methods to fetch the data.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_get.asp

Comment: @Praveen Kumar A quick Google search turns up W3Schools, MDN, MSDN, and several other sites. Take your pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you cannot click on the `<a>` tag, because of its empty nature. You do not have a clickable area. But although, you can make it clickable by giving some `padding` or setting `width` and `height` through CSS.

Secondly, the way you need to get the contents of the `<p>` tag is:

```
$(function() {
    $(".image").click(function() {
        $(this).next("header").find("p").text();
    });
});
```

Finally, the class naming. The class `4u 12u(mobile)` I am not sure if this is valid. It would be better to change it to something like `4u 12u-mobile`.

Comment: OP got's an id for header. I think $('#dynamicCampingDesc13 p').text() would be much faster and straight.

Comment: @PraveenKumar class name is valid and in working condition.

Comment: Worked !! 
Thanks @PraveenKumar

Comment: @TaufikPirjade Enjoy! `:)`

Comment: @DinoMyte I know. I was just thinking if that would be dynamic.